# Double-ended Queue in Clojure

Tags: clojure, queue, interop

Is there a double-ended queue in Clojure?  My impression is Clojure's `PersistentQueue` is single ended (am I wrong?). I need to be able to remove (i.e. "pop") and "peek" at data from either end of the queue. An explanation of what I mean by a double-ended queue is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-ended_queue.

I see that Java has a double-ended queue, but I'm unsure how to instantiate the queue object in Clojure.
Tried creating a new queue with:

```
(java.util.Dequeue.)
```

Gives error:

> No matching ctor found for interface java.util.Queue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is there a double-ended queue in Clojure?

AFAIK no.

> My impression is Clojure's `PersistentQueue` is single ended (am I wrong?).

It only allows `conj` at end and `peek`/`pop` from beginning.

> I see that Java has a double-ended queue, but I'm unsure how to instantiate the queue object in Clojure.

You can't instantiate [`java.util.Queue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html) because it's an [interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html). Have a look at the subinterface [`java.util.Deque`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html) and its implementing classes:

- [`ArrayDeque`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayDeque.html)
- [`ConcurrentLinkedDeque`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedDeque.html)
- [`LinkedBlockingDeque`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingDeque.html)
- [`LinkedList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html)

You can create and use, for instance, an `ArrayDeque` as follows:

```
(def deque (java.util.ArrayDeque. [1 2 3]))
;;=> 'user/deque

(.pollFirst deque)
;;=> 1
```

However, rather than struggling with interop syntax and mutable collections, you may want to check out [deque-clojure](https://github.com/pjstadig/deque-clojure) which offers a persistent implementation in Clojure.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  Actually in my question I meant **java.util.DeQueue** rather than **java.util.Queue**.  But, your answer holds regardless (I'll correct my question).  Especially thanks for the suggestion of java.util.ArrayDeque (which provides an implementation for Deque).  I had seen [deque-clojure](https://github.com/pjstadig/deque-clojure/blob/master/test/name/stadig/test/deque.clj) but hoped there was something simpler (I couldn't follow the code).

Answer (score 3):

Just for completenes, a pure clojure version may look like this:

```
(defn deque 
  ([]
   '[()()])
  ([& elems]
   [elems '()]))

(defn push-front [deque elem]
  (let [[head tail] deque]
    [(cons elem head) tail]))

(defn push-back [deque elem]
  (let [[head tail] deque]
    [head (cons elem tail)]))

(defn pop-front [deque]
  (let [[head tail] deque]
    (if (empty? head)
      [(-> tail reverse rest) head]
      [(rest head) tail])))

(defn pop-back [deque]
  (let [[head tail] deque]
    (if (empty? tail)
      [tail (-> head reverse rest)]
      [head (rest tail)])))

(defn peek-front [deque]
  (let [[head tail] deque]
    (if (empty? head)
      (-> tail reverse first)
      (first head))))

(defn peek-back [deque]
  (let [[head tail] deque]
    (if (empty? tail)
      (-> head reverse first)
      (first tail))))


;; usage example:

user> (let [dq (deque )]
        (-> dq 
            (push-front :a)
            (push-front :b)
            (peek-back)))


:a
user> (let [dq (deque )]
        (-> dq 
            (push-front :a)
            (push-front :b)
            (pop-back)))


[() (:b)]

user> (let [dq (deque )]
    (-> dq 
        (push-back :a)
        (push-back :b)
        (peek-back)))
:b
```